# Xcode 13.2 command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-m1, carthage

While building my project, I get this error:

```
line 2: /usr/local/bin/carthage: No such file or directory. Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Tried so many methods to resolve this issue, including switching Xcode versions.
It's worth to mention that **it only occurs on an M1 Mac device** which I'm currently using, same project without changing any part of the configurations works on an Intel Mac.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The project is using [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage), which is likely installed using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh). On M1 Macs, Homebrew links its binaries into `/opt/homebrew/bin` while on Intel Macs, they are linked into `/usr/local/bin`.

This means that on an M1 Mac, Carthage is probably found at `/opt/homebrew/bin/cartage`.

Your build script should use something like `$(which carthage)` or simply `carthage` instead of relying on an absolute installation path.

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution and for saving my day! the 'carthage' path didn't work, but it gave me an idea to find the correct path which was: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/carthage/0.38.0/bin/carthage copy-frameworks

Comment: Be aware that this will only work as long as the Carthage version is 0.38.0. There should be a convenience link at `/opt/homebrew/opt/carthage/bin/carthage`.

Comment: Well aware of that. It won't be a problem as long as the method works.

Comment: hi @MakwanBarzan Can you explain exactly how you did it? I am currently struggling with the same error. thank you

Comment: Hi @YunusDikenlitarla, you must alter the Carthage linking path by using this command: ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/carthage /usr/local/bin/carthage

Comment: python: command not found. I have the same error with this issue @FlorianFriedrich

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error. My issue was that I didn't have a `~/.bash_profile`. Creating an empty file fixed the error